# conjure-up openstack launch instance no console & ssh

Tags: ssh, openstack, console, conjure-up

after conjure-up openstack installed, create instance with default 2 images (trusty-lxd & xenial-lxd), but the instance console said "console is currently unavailable. Please try again later.", and tried ssh to ubuntu@10.99.0.14 return "ssh: connect to host 10.99.0.14 port 22: No route to host"

ub14    trusty-lxd  10.99.0.15 m1.small -   Active  nova    None    Running     30 minutes
ub16test    xenial-lxd  10.99.0.14 m1.medium    -   Active  nova    None    Running     34 minutes

log end with following message:
-----END SSH HOST KEY KEYS-----
[35802.789041] cloud-init[330]: Cloud-init v. 0.7.9 running 'modules:final' at Sat, 04 Mar 2017 00:04:04 +0000. Up 430.0 seconds.
[35802.789188] cloud-init[330]: ci-info: no authorized ssh keys fingerprints found for user ubuntu.
[35802.789266] cloud-init[330]: Cloud-init v. 0.7.9 finished at Sat, 04 Mar 2017 00:04:04 +0000. Datasource DataSourceNone.  Up 430.0 seconds
[35802.789325] cloud-init[330]: 2017-03-04 00:04:04,084 - cc_final_message.py[WARNING]: Used fallback datasource
[  OK  ] Started Execute cloud user/final scripts.
[  OK  ] Reached target Cloud-init target.

Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS ubuntu console

ubuntu login:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lets start from this situation, assign a floating IP

[image]
[image]
[image]

on the machine where you've installed Openstack via conjure check the status of juju environment

```
$: juju status
```

look for the container dedicated to nova-compute,

[image]

in my case the machine is 13 and its own IP addr. is 10.0.8.85

```
nova-compute/0*           active    idle       13       10.0.8.85                       Unit is ready
```

now you need to list the containers created with lxc

`$: lxc list`

[image]

locate the name used from lxc for that IP (10.0.8.85). Now run:

```
$: lxc exec juju-d30ce2-13 bash
root@juju-d30ce2-13:~#
```

from there run

```
$: lxc list
```

[image]

there you find yours instances created via Openstack, again

```
$: lxc exec instance-00000005 -- bash
```

and as last step is edit the ssh_config file

```
$: nano /etc/ssh/ssh_config
```

and uncomment the following lines as reports the picture
[image]

reload the instance 
[image]

now you can do the ssh connection

```
$: ssh root@10.99.0.7
The authenticity of host '10.99.0.7 (10.99.0.7)' can't be established.
ECDSA key fingerprint is SHA256:BGh/0LipzF3IgfaHwwKl2gl45uy9h3ctS5w/h469Om4.
Are you sure you want to continue connecting (yes/no)? yes
```

thats it.

Answer (score 0):

LXD containers don't have console devices.  List container names:

```
lxc list
```

Then connect to one:

```
lxc exec <container_name> bash
```